# MongoDB timeouts after config server issue

Tags: mongodb, crash, timeout

So, i have a very weird issue. Yesterday my Config Server Replica Set basically stopped working and the only way I could get it back was restoring the contents of it with the backup and re-creating the replica set.

So far it looked good, all sharding data and so is visible via sh.status() on the config servers. Also on the two replicasets I can query the data.

But, on the mongos instances I am getting timouts when trying to get the shard status:

```
mongos> sh.status()
2016-09-05T09:49:15.645+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error: { "code" : 50, "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "Operation timed out" } :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCommandCursor@src/mongo/shell/query.js:689:1
DBQuery.prototype._exec@src/mongo/shell/query.js:118:28
DBQuery.prototype.hasNext@src/mongo/shell/query.js:276:5
DBCollection.prototype.findOne@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:289:10
printShardingStatus@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:540:19
sh.status@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:78:5
@(shell):1:1
```

I can connect to the config server via mongo from the server running the mongos. Using Mongo version 3.2.7 , I have no idea how to solve this issue as I do not see any logs pointing me into the right direction...

The only thing in the logs on the config servers is this:

```
2016-09-05T10:09:35.549+0000 I COMMAND  [conn1243] Command on database config timed out waiting for read concern to be satisfied. Command: { find: "shards", readConcern: { level: "majority", afterOpTime: { ts: Timestamp 1472281864000|2, t: 30 } }, maxTimeMS: 30000 }
2016-09-05T10:09:35.551+0000 I COMMAND  [conn1243] command config.$cmd command: find { find: "shards", readConcern: { level: "majority", afterOpTime: { ts: Timestamp 1472281864000|2, t: 30 } }, maxTimeMS: 30000 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:92 locks:{} protocol:op_command 30409ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action is dangerous, you should not just restore your config server. This may lead to inconsistency cluster metadata.

While you are using replset config server, mongos will maintain a ConfigOpTime which is the latest committed OpTime in config server. This is used as a value of the request argument(AfterOpTime of the ReadConcern) sent to config server so that mongos will not read data that may be rollbacked later. Mongos gets this ConfigOpTime through response of config server or other shards.

So in your case, you restore your config server, leading new election thus new term of OpTime. But the other shards still cached old config server's OpTime. And usually it has higher term. Mongos use this higher ConfigOpTime to demand config server give data after this. It must wait until config server reaches this time(If no new election occurs, it's impossible).

If you are sure the cluster metadata is ok, try to restart all your mongodb shards before restarting your mongos.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. But what I then do not understand, if I restore the config servers and also restart all shards and mongos, shouldn't it then use the "new" OpTime from the Config servers? Regarding my issue, I ended up dumping the data from the two shards, recreating the cluster from scratch an then dumping the data back via a mongos. This worked as I do not yet have a big amount of data, but it will be a problem in the future.

Comment: Yes. If you restart all shards and mongos after restoring the config server, they will use the "new" OpTime from the config server. You can refer to this [sharded cluster restore tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/restore-sharded-cluster/) as your future operation guide.